# How to filter Django serializer data?

Tags: python-3.x, django, serialization

I'm trying to filter data based on userName in JWT. This is how I've been trying to do it:

views.py:

```
class TestView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def get(self, request):
        token = request.META.get('HTTP_AUTHORIZATION', " ").split(' ')[1]
        data = {'token': token}
        try:
            valid_data = VerifyJSONWebTokenSerializer().validate(data)
            user = valid_data['user']
            request.user = user
            person = Person.objects.filter(userName=request.user)
        except ValidationError as v:
            print("validation error", v)
        return Response(person[0])
```

This works as I can get the Person data with  `print("Person: ", person[0])`. The `return Response(person[0])` however returns an error: `TypeError: Object of type Person is not JSON serializable`. I guess I could use a serializer class to return a valid JSON, am I right? I have this in my `serializers.py`:

```
class TestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = '__all__'
```

I just don't know how to use this with my view. If I use serializer instead of `person = Person.objects.filter(userName=request.user)`, how is the filtering supposed to be done?

Please correct me if I'm not on right track at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add serializer to view, provide query result to serializer and get serialized data:

```py
class TestView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = TestSerializer  # add serializer

    def get(self, request):
        token = request.META.get('HTTP_AUTHORIZATION', " ").split(' ')[1]
        data = {'token': token}
        try:
            valid_data = VerifyJSONWebTokenSerializer().validate(data)
            user = valid_data['user']
            request.user = user
            person = Person.objects.filter(userName=request.user).last()
            data = self.serializer_class(instance=person).data  # serialize query result
        except ValidationError as v:
            print("validation error", v)
            raise v
        return Response(data)  # return serialized response
```

[Here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/3-class-based-views/) you can find some examples of using serializer with class based views.

Also note that your `Person` model might have security-sensitive fields like password, etc, so it's better to specify exact fields you need in serializer rather then use `fields = '__all__'`.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I get an error `TypeError: 'ReturnDict' object is not callable ` from row `data = self.serializer_class(instance=person).data()`. Any ideas why this happens?

Comment: With `data = self.serializer_class(instance=person).data` it works. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry for redundant backets : /

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Django-Rest-Framework (based on your use of `ModelSerializer`)?

In pure Django, from the [documentation on serializers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/serialization/), you can do something like:

```py
from django.core import serializers
json_response = serializers.serialize("json", person[0])
return Response(json_response)
```

If you are using Django-Rest-Framework:

```py
return Response(TestSerializer(person[0]).data)
```

Comment: This works also, thank you for your help.Could be the accepted answer as well but the other one was a bit faster.